# What GIS software is required to export a GIS map as a hi-res raster image?

Tags: raster, export, free-software

I am looking for some (preferably free) GIS software that will enable me to export multi-layered world maps (made up of shapefiles and KML files and so on...) as high resolution (21,000 pixels wide), single layered TIFF, JPEG or other raster format files, so that I can then edit them in Photoshop.

I am an artist, and new to GIS. I have recently started running the free MapWindow program on my computer. This has enabled me to start constructing some of the world maps that I'm looking for, though I can't seem to find a way of exporting them as images from that program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try Qgis? I think wil cover you. You wil find a lot of help on Internet. It is very easy to manipulate the data. If you want to change their style or icons it is very easy. And of course Tiff export is a standard. Is open source and cross platform, that mean you can install it in any Opereting System.

More info:
From [here](http://www.qgis.org/)

Download:
From [here](http://www.qgis.org/) [Standalone Installer (recommended for new users)]

Comment: Thanks for that. Im just downloading it now. It sounds like just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think QGIS is the best option. In the built-in print composer you will be able to export in raster, vector o PDF format in any dimension and resolution you may like. Here you can find the User's Guide section on this topic: http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/index.html .